# how to get imsi number in android using command line

Tags: android, shell, android-intent, adb

I want to get `IMSI` number of SIM of `Android` phone using command line.

Is there any adb command or any shell command in android for this???

I tried `adb shell getprop ril.IMSI` command in Samsung Galaxy ace, it works. It gives me `IMSI` number. But I tried the same command in Samsung Galaxy S3. It doesn't return anything.

I want to get `IMSI` number of SIM card in `Samsung Galaxy S3` using command line only. (Not Android Application code) either using `adb` command or some shell command in `Android`.

Also, I know there is a simple code in `JAVA` to run in Android Application which gives `IMSI` number:

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imsi = mTelephonyMgr.getSubscriberId();
```

Can I somehow run this `Android Java` code from command line? This will also solve my problem.

Answer (score 8):

To call `TelephonyManager.getSubscriberId()` in Android versions 5.x-7.x via `adb shell` run:

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 7
```

This command no longer (i.e. on most 6.0+ devices) requires the device to be rooted.

For *proper* parsing of the `service call` command output on the device side and without external dependencies see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29357619/1778421)

Also read [Calling Android services from ADB shell](http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/calling-android-services-from-adb-shell.html) for more details.

Comment: My phone is not Rooted. I checked with above command. But didn't work. It gives an big error saying:" ..Requires READ_PHONE_STATE:  Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission .READ_PHONE_STATE"

Answer (score 2):

```
adb shell getprop ril.iccid.sim1
```

If you want to know all data you can use only `adb shell getprop`, that shows you all of them, and you see that some items show you the IMSI like item `ril.iccid.sim1` or `persist.radio.cfu.iccid.0`

Comment: @AmitaiFensterheim, Although the property manager might be standard in Android, access to it is certainly not. On my Samsung S6, `getprop` is a symlink to `toolbox`. It is likely to be different across vendors, let alone devices. Vendors may also choose to name their properties differently, or restrict access from userland altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get ccid using command from java code.

```
public static String getSIMCCIDByCmd() {
        try {
            Process getSimCCIDProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"getprop", "ril.iccid.sim1"});
            try (final BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getSimCCIDProc.getInputStream()))) {
                String ccid = b.readLine();
                return ccid;
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                DadsHelper.LOG(TAG, "Exception while reading inputstream", e);
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            DadsHelper.LOG(TAG,"Exception in getSIMCCID",e);

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Above code uses: getprop command to fetch value from property manager.

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell getprop persist.radio.ddssim.iccid
```

This worked for me on my Oneplus device. Like @j140781 mentioned, try `adb shell getprop` to get all the data, and then try to find items that start either with `persist.radio.` or `ril.iccid.`

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me on a rooted Android 10 Moto G7 Plus:

```
adb shell
su
```

then once you are in the root shell:

```
service call iphonesubinfo 7 | tail -3 | sed s/\'\)// | awk '{print $NF}' | sed s/[\'\.]//g | tr -d \\n
```