# How to get Nokia S30+'s MRE vxp file to run on nokia 225?

Tags: c++, nokia

## The setup

Ok let's me talk a bit about the setup:

I have installed Visual Studio 2008 (the edition that let you try for 90 days), MRE SDK 3.0 from [this Github issue](https://github.com/UstadMobile/ustadmobile-mre/issues/2), [Sourcery Codebench Lite for ARM EABI](https://download.informer.com/win-1195143593-719db346-6cf10103/arm-2011.09-69-arm-none-eabi.exe) and also ARM Realview Development suite 3.1 (but it requires license, and I am too lazy to cr@ck it, also I prefer the open source GCC to that commercial software). I set the compiler to Sourcery Codebench's GCC.

I can compile and run `vxp` file on Mediatek's emulator without any problem.

## The problem

After compile for ARM platform, here's the output in `[project_dir]\arm`:
[image: vxp]

I tried copying the `Default.vxp` to my Nokia 255's SD card, then open that file on my phone, but the phone said `Can't open this app at the moment`.

I also try creating an `appmanager` folder on my SD card, then my phone's internal storage, then copy the `vxp` file there, but in the app list, there is still no app other than stock apps, and the `vxp` file still not run.

## Other vxp files

I downloaded some `vxp` files from `http://shifat100.xtgem.com/`, put to my SD card and run from it. Some will work, for example the Asphalt 6 Game, but some won't, for example the Gold rush game, they yelt `Can't open this app at the moment`.

I checked the format of the Asphalt 6 game 's `vxp` with the `file` command, and it said `data`. But I check my `Default.vxp`, it was ELF. I think this is the problem, but don't know how to convert/pack ELF to vxp.

Using binwalk with the Asphalt 6 game 's `vxp`, I get 2 zlib compressed files and 2 GIFs, which are icons of the game. The two compressed files, after unpack, one contain many names, for example

```
splash_320x240.bsprite
splash_menu_320x240_200k.bsprite
splash_menu_split_320x240_200k.bsprite
splash_title.bsprite
hollywood_320x240_200k.bsprite
new.png
font_small.bsprite
font_large.bsprite
interface_font.bsprite
copter.bsprite
car_tourist.bsprite
cars_fx.bsprite
cars_shadow.bsprite
```

so I think this is the resource file. The other might contain code, I found some exception strings in it, for example

```
Unknown signal
Invalid Operation
Divide By Zero
Overflow
Underflow
Inexact Result
: Heap memory corrupted
Abnormal termination
Arithmetic exception:
Illegal instruction
Interrupt received
Illegal address
Termination request
Stack overflow
Redirect: can't open:
Out of heap memory
User-defined signal 1
User-defined signal 2
Pure virtual fn called
C++ library exception
```

and some (maybe) S30+ platform APIs, for example

```
vm_get_mre_modules
vm_get_mre_total_mem_size
vm_get_mre_version
```

So what might be the problem? Screen resolution? I changed it but still not work. SDK version? I also tried all 3 version, but no luck. File format? Compiler difference? (Note that I'm using GCC while most tutorial left on the internet suggest using RVCS) I don't know.

Any ideas? Thanks!

If you need to get any files, tell me and I will put it here.

Comment: It *seems* that the phone will only run the apps in the list of installed apps & downloadable apps in the store. It will not run the others.

Comment: No, I can confirm that Nokia 225 can run ELF. Opera mini's vxp file in ELF format is an example.

Comment: No solution here but just to tell  you i am also interested in running app in s30+ series.

Comment: I can confirm that IT WORKED!! The answer will be posted here tomorrow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delivered from [my answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/30573/40846) at [RE.SE](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com)

---

First I want to say thanks to people at 4pda forum. See their thread [here](https://4pda.to/forum/index.php?showtopic=1041371&st=0).

> Can you figure out informations about the MRE VXP format

Well I haven't found yet, need further research

> how to get it signed

Short answer:

Step 1: Get your **SIM 1**'s **IMSI** number (**NOT** IMEI, they are **DIFFERENT!**)

You can do this in multiple ways, but the easiest way is to plug the SIM 1 in to an Android phone and read. I personally [use ADB to read IMSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813875/how-to-get-imsi-number-in-android-using-command-line) (worked on Android 6+ without root):

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 7
```

Step 2: Go to https://vxpatch.luxferre.top/ and input the IMSI number you got in step 1. Then select your VXP file, click 'Patch' and you should be able to download a patched version.

or

You can enter the IMSI number in the project setting, but **REMEMBER TO ADD 9 BEFORE THE IMSI NUMBER**

[image: imsi]

Step 3: Move the patched version into a SD card and plug it in your phone
Step 4: Find the vxp file and click open, your app should run now!

Long answer:
Some apps doesn't require specify the IMSI, they just work on any devices. That's because they use another way of signing, using RSA key.

If you are interested, read [here](https://4pda.to/forum/index.php?showtopic=1041371&st=20#:%7E:text=%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20RSA%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%85%20(%D1%83%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%2C%20%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9)%0A%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%20%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%20(%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%20Ximik_Boda%20%23111714051)%0A%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%20%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%20(%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%20Ximik_Boda%20%23107895102)). The text is in Russian, so use Google Translate if you want to.

I have tested with ADS 1.2 compiler (I cracked myself, if you want it then tell me) and GCC (Smaller size + work very well) and Nokia 225, will continue to test further!

The apps in S30+ platform are written in C (and optionally C++), so you can port many apps to S30+

Again, a great thanks to people at 4pda forum!

An image of the app running after signing:

[image: image of the app]